# Manipulating DOM of Multiple dijit Widget Instances

Tags: javascript, dom, widget, dojo

I have developed a custom dijit Templated Widget.  I have to do some DOM manipulation of the children of the `containerNode`.  Everything works fine, except when I have two of the Widgets loaded, and the manipulation of the children of the `containerNode` seems to affect all of the Widgets of the same type, not just the particular instance of the widget.

I think I have narrowed it down to this part of my code where I "unload" the "children" I am executing the following function:

```
popPage: function() {
  if (this._pagesLoaded) {
    var i = this._pagesLoaded - 1;
    var y = this.containerNode.children[i];
    if (typeof y !== "undefined") {
      this.containerNode.removeChild(y);
    }
    var page = this.pages.pop();
    page.unsetPage(); //Internal sub object cleanup
    page.destroyRecursive();
    this.endPageLoaded--;
    this._calcPagesLoaded();  //recalcs this._pagesLoaded
  }
},
```

When I seem to execute this, it seems that the child is removed from the DOM of all Widgets.  It just doesn't make any sense, and manually inspecting things in Firebug (like `dijit.byId("logScroller62").containerNode.children`) shows that the browser thinks everything is seperate and I get two different sets of results for two different instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I had an initialisation/scoping issue.  I was keeping my child objects in an array.  I had initialised the array in the property definition of my dojo Object Prototype by doing the following:

```
pages: [],
```

But it seems that this causes a scoping issue, as simple change to:

```
pages: null,
```

And then adding the initialisation to the `postCreate` function of the Widget like:

```
this.pages = [];
```

Seems to have fixed the problem.  I am not sure why something like this causes a scoping issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your description, but the error seems to be here:

> it seems that the child is removed from the DOM of all Widgets

A DOMNode can't be the child of multiple DOMNodes, nor can a widget be the child of multiple widgets at once.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what appears to be happening, is I execute the above code to remove the child DOM nodes from Widget instance A, but it removes the same index of the child node from all instances of Widget (e.g. B, C, etc).

Comment: OK, can't see your code but I'm guessing that this.containerNode.children is an array that's getting shared across multiple instances because you declared it in the prototype of something.

Comment: Yeah, that is my guess too... I am going to go back over the code, but I don't directly declare it, as `containerNode` is set automatically by the `dijit._Templated` HTML template.  I may have screwed it up somehow, but I don't think so.

Comment: Sorry, bill, I didn't realise you actually told me exactly what the problem was in your comment...  Why does setting something in the prototype cause that?

Comment: There's one prototype object that's shared across all instances.   Usually when you say something like myObject.foo = 5, it sets "foo" in myObject, thus masking the value of foo in that shared prototype... no problem.

However, something like myObject.foo.bar = 5 will adjust the value of bar inside the foo in the prototype.